# How to read the two type parameters infront of the chunk method in Spring Batch StepBuilder?

Tags: java, spring-batch

From the official Spring Batch documentation https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/step.html#configuringAStep

```
@Bean
public Step sampleStep(JobRepository jobRepository, PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager) {
    return new StepBuilder("sampleStep", jobRepository)
                .<String, String>chunk(10, transactionManager) // <-- (*)
                .reader(itemReader())
                .writer(itemWriter())
                .build();
}
```

I'm not sure how to read the line `(*)`, especially the `<String, String>` part. Its two type parameters, but what does it mean here? Like "Read a String Type and write to a String type"?
The syntax is confusing to me.. Is this similar to like instantiating an array list like `List a = new ArrayList<Integer>()`? What confuses me is that the type parameters are at the start of the `chunk` method invocation. How to read this?

Comment: Yes, it's similar to `new ArrayList<String>`. The difference is that's a constructor, and this is a method. So this syntax is how you pass type arguments to a method. Usually you don't have to, because the compiler will infer them for you.

Answer (score 1):

Those types represent the input and output item type of the step. This notation enforces type-safety at compile time to make sure you are passing an item reader and an item writer with the expected input and output types.

The output type can be different from the input type if you use an item processor that changes the type.